# Python print statement dependent on lines following it?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code:

```
for file_name, content in corpus.items():
    print('here')
    content = [list(filter(lambda index: index not in remove_indices, content))]
    corpus[file_name] = np.array(content).astype(np.uint32)
```

Where corpus is a 800,000 long dictionary with string keys and array values.

Things were taking forever so I decided to check how fast each iteration was by adding in that print statement.

If I **comment the last two lines** out it prints lots of `here`s really fast, so there's no problem with my iterator. What's really weird is that when I **uncomment the last two lines**, `here` takes a long time to print, even for the first one! It's like the print statement is somehow aware of the lines that follow it.

I guess my question speaks for itself. I'm in Jupyter notebook, if that helps.

Comment: You can use [tqdm](https://tqdm.github.io/), instead of `print`.

Comment: yes it's what I was using, but I ended up suspecting it was causing issues. Thanks